# Alternative text if data is not available

Tags: react-native

**In React Native, how can I specify an alternative text to use if data is not available?**

For example, in the following code, how would I specify to display *"no skills, yet"*, if the skills array is empty?

```
<View>
    <Text>
        Skills
    </Text> 
    <View>{
        p.skills && p.skills.map( skill => 
            <Text key={skill}>
                { skill }
            </Text>                                        
        )
    }</View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either save the desired output in a variable before rendering:

```
let skillText = (<Text>{'no skills, yet'}</Text>);
if (p.skills && p.skills.length > 0) {
   skillText = p.skills.map( skill => 
                    <Text key={skill}>
                        { skill }
                    </Text>                                        
                );
}
...some more code...
<View>
    <Text>
        Skills
    </Text> 
    <View>{ skillText }</View>
</View>
```

Or use a ternary directly in the jsx:

```
<View>
    <Text>
        Skills
    </Text> 
    <View>{
        (p.skills && p.skills.length > 0) ? p.skills.map( skill => 
            <Text key={skill}>
                { skill }
            </Text>                                        
        ) : 'no skills, yet'
    }</View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

First way (short one):

```
<View>
  <Text>
    Skills
  </Text>
  <View>
    {
      (p.skills && p.skills.length > 0) ? p.skills.map( skill =>
        <Text key={skill}>
          { skill }
        </Text>
      ) : (
        <Text>no skills, yet</Text>
      )
    }
  </View>
</View>
```

Second way: Extract the list rendering into a separate method

```
renderSkills = () => {
  if (p.skills && p.skills.length > 0) {
    return p.skills.map( skill =>
      <Text key={skill}>
        { skill }
      </Text>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <Text>no skills, yet</Text>
    )
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        Skills
      </Text>
      <View>
        {this.renderSkills()}
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

PS: Please consider to use `FlatList` instead of rendering rows using `Text` (it helps a lot with performance)